# 2 Distinct Bijective functions

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have that A is a set of $2k^2$ so it equals $\{2,8,18,32,50...\}$
How do you Construct two distinct bijections $f, g : \mathbb{Z}^{+} \to A$.

I was able to get $f(x)=2x^2$
what would $g(x)$ be?

Thank You

Comment: If there are no restrictions on the map, you could swap two element. So sent 1 to 8 and 2 to 2 and leave the rest equal to $f$.

Comment: How about $g(1)=8$, $g(2)=2$, and $g(x)=2x^2$ for $x\geq 3$.

Comment: That would work but I do not think that I would be able to do that. I need a whole new function of some sort that is also a bijection. Thank you though

Comment: Any non-identity bijection $p:\mathbb Z^+\to\mathbb Z^+$ lets you choose $g(x)=f(p(x))$. It's not clear what you mean by "whole new function," but every bijection from $\mathbb Z^+$ and $A$ will be of this form.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't understand what you mean exactly sorry

By whole function I mean something like g(x)=something that ends up being a bijection with a different map than f(x)

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews By your inference, what would be a valid g(x)?

Answer (score 1):

As written DKal's comment is an answer to the question.  It is a function, as it assigns a unique element of the range to each element of the domain.  It is a different function, as it disagrees with $f(x)$ for $x \in \{1,2\}$  Many posters (and it seems you) believe that a function has to have a "simple formula".  This is simply not true.  In particular, there is resistance to definition by cases.  We could show DKal's example as $$g(x)=\begin {cases} 8&x=1\\1&x=2\\2x^2& \text{otherwise} \end {cases}$$  To follow up on Thomas Andrews' suggestion define $$p(x)=\begin {cases} x+1 & x \text { odd}\\ x-1 & x\text { even}  \end {cases}$$  Then $x \leftrightarrow f(p(x))$ is a different bijection than $x \leftrightarrow f(x)$